# Sofware update, start apk, FATAL EXCEPTION: Activity not found to handle intent (Working with prefix file://), Having issue using getExternalFilesDir

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-file, start-activity

I'm creating application custom updater, I found lot of help from here, but not for this issue.

I can download update.apk using AsyncTask like this:

```
output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()+"/update.apk");
```

Download completes succesfully, then try to run apk to update software like this:

**EDIT:** This part corrected as ligi suggested. **("file://")**

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+context.getFilesDir()+"/update.apk"),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(promptInstall);
```

App crashed with error above, before added prefix.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
    No Activity found to handle Intent { 
        act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/data/data/com.my.app/files/update.apk 
        typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000001 
    }
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I try to do it like this and get error:

**/strorage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files open failed: EISDIR**

```
String PATH = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/";
File file = new File(PATH);
file.mkdirs();
File outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");
output = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

And try to start install as suggested

```
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/update.apk");
file.setReadable(true, false);
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(promptInstall);
```

What i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

I forgot to add permission to read from external storage, added this line into

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**AsyncTask**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground (String...sUrl){
    ......
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File outputFile = new File(sd, "/download/update.apk");
    output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    ......
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ......
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File inputFile = new File(sd, "/download/update.apk");

    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(inputFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(promptInstall);
    ......
}
```

Comment: is your activity well declared in the manifest?

Comment: Activity is well declared in manifest, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `Uri.fromFile()` for files, not `Uri.parse()`, to avoid the `file:///` scheme problem that ligi cites.

Second, the installer cannot access the APK, because you put it on internal storage. You have to put the APK file on external storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`).

Comment: Does getExternalFilesDir means that I have to have sdcard mounted on the device? Somehow I can't get it working. @CommonsWare

Comment: I get this error while trying to use **getExternalFilesDir** `/strorage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files`  **open failed: EISDIR**

Comment: @EspeH: "Does getExternalFilesDir means that I have to have sdcard mounted on the device?" -- [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most devices. "open failed: EISDIR" -- `getExternalFilesDir()` is a directory, not a file.

Comment: I edit my question to show how I try to use getExternalFilesDir

Comment: @CommonWare now I edited question, so if you have time to check what is wrong, Thank you so far.

Answer (score 3):

you need to prefix schema ( file:// )

Comment: Great, now it starts update, but there is some problem with parsing, installer says,     An error occurred while parsing the package, what would be the problem? Apk file is correctly generated, and I can istall app when manually downloading file and install.

Comment: you should ask this as a separate question and accept this one